# C alloc / free struct arr

Tags: c, struct, free, alloc

I want to be sure it's correct because idk how to verify it surelly without any complex tools or trackers (maybe it's possible \w gdb).
I malloc arr of struct as this:

```
typedef struct {
     int a;
} A;
A *arr = malloc(sizeof *arr * 5);
arr[2].a = -9;
```

Then to free a simple

```
free(arr); //because it's not an array of pointers of structs
```

Is it correct way to free ?

Comment: Yes.  Just pass the same pointer to `free` that `malloc` returned.

Comment: valgrind and AddressSanitizer are good tools for helping to find mistakes in memory allocation.  They're not really complex to use.

Comment: "//because it's not an array of pointers of structs" that is irrelevant but... your code is correct

Comment: @4386427 it's because if I make an array of pointers of struct I have to ``` for (i in arr) free(arr[i]); free(arr) ``

Comment: @NateEldredge I will check thanks

Comment: @KV yep, a simple rule... The number of `free` must equal the number of `malloc`